# Modifying empty matrix given matrix of positions and vector of values

Tags: r, matrix

Given the following setup:

```
> vals = matrix(nrow = 3,ncol = 4)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA

> position =  matrix(c(4,2,1, 6,3,2, NA,NA,3, NA,NA,4), nrow = 3, ncol = 4)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4   NA   NA
[2,]    2    3   NA   NA
[3,]    1    2    3    4

> temp = c(10, 5, 8, 6, 9, 2, 4, 3)
```

I'm trying to populate `vals` with the values held in `temp`. However, the values must be placed in the spots given by `position`. Specifically, each row in `position` represents a row in `vals`, and the values represent the column in which the value must be placed.

For example, `position[2,2] = 3`. Since that's position's second row, the respective value must go into `vals[2,3]`. The final result would be:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   10   NA   NA    5
[2,]   NA    8    6   NA
[3,]    9    2    4    3
```

This would be straightforward with for-loops, but can it be done without them?

Comment: Are apply or map functions allowed?

Comment: @gersht everything is allowed. If relevant, you can also change NA to NULL (I'm a beginner and don't know if that distinction is meaningful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a row/column indexing by `cbind`ing the `row` index (created with `row`, `c` -> convert the numeric index matrix to vector), with the column index by transposing the 'position', coerce it to vector (`c`), remove the NA elements (`na.omit`), extract the elements in 'vals' based on the indexes and assign (`<-`) to 'temp'

```
vals[na.omit(cbind(c(t(row(position))), c(t(position))))] <- temp
vals
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   10   NA   NA    5
#[2,]   NA    8    6   NA
#[3,]    9    2    4    3
```

#### data

```
position <- structure(c(1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, 4), .Dim = 3:4)
```

Comment: This looks promising, but the output isn't correct. You table has first row `10, 2, NA, NA`, but it should be `10, NA, NA, 5` (since the first row of position is `1, 4, NA, NA`). I got it to work by transposing `row(position)` as well.

Comment: @Wasabi  Thank you for spotting that.  I forgot to `t` the `row`. For `data.frame/matrix` etc. it is columnwise unwinding.  But, we need it to be rowwise.  Now, it should work